# Highlighting multiple cells in different colors with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, highlight, pandas-styles

Imagine we have a dataframe and I want to color different cells:

- Cells `['Arizona','company'](1st)`, `['Texas','size'](1099)` as green.
- Cells `['Florida','veterans'](26)`, `['Maine','armored'](0)` as red.

What's a good way to do it?

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': [523, 52, 25, 616, 43, 234, 523, 62, 62, 73, 37, 35],
            'battles': [5, 42, 2, 2, 4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
            'size': [1045, 957, 1099, 1400, 1592, 1006, 987, 849, 973, 1005, 1099, 1523],
            'veterans': [1, 5, 62, 26, 73, 37, 949, 48, 48, 435, 63, 345],
            'readiness': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
            'armored': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            'deserters': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
            'origin': ['Arizona', 'California', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Maine', 'Iowa', 'Alaska', 'Washington', 'Oregon', 'Wyoming', 'Louisana', 'Georgia']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'deaths', 'battles', 'size', 'veterans', 'readiness', 'armored', 'deserters', 'origin'])

df = df.set_index('origin')

df.head()
```

(http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_indexing_selecting.html)

Comment: how do you want to save this data to excel , html or something else ?

Comment: I actually want to display the dataframe in IPython Notebook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [slicing in Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Slicing) with parameter `subset` and function `Styler.applymap` for elementwise styles, run code in `jupyter notebook`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def red(val):
    color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

def green(val):
    color = 'green'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': [523, 52, 25, 616, 43, 234, 523, 62, 62, 73, 37, 35],
            'battles': [5, 42, 2, 2, 4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
            'size': [1045, 957, 1099, 1400, 1592, 1006, 987, 849, 973, 1005, 1099, 1523],
            'veterans': [1, 5, 62, 26, 73, 37, 949, 48, 48, 435, 63, 345],
            'readiness': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
            'armored': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            'deserters': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
            'origin': ['Arizona', 'California', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Maine', 'Iowa', 'Alaska', 'Washington', 'Oregon', 'Wyoming', 'Louisana', 'Georgia']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'deaths', 'battles', 'size', 'veterans', 'readiness', 'armored', 'deserters', 'origin'])

df = df.set_index('origin')
print (df)

df.style.applymap(green, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Arizona':'Texas', 'company': 'size'])
        .applymap(red, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Florida':'Maine', 'veterans': 'armored'])
```

If need change only some values in `DataFrame`, you can use `Styler.apply` with `axis=None` for tablewise styles, also  the function must return a `DataFrame` with the same index and column labels:

```
def create_colors(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df1 = x.copy()
    #select all values to default value - no color
    df1.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: '
    #overwrite values with green and red color
    df1.loc['Arizona', 'company'] = 'background-color: green'
    df1.loc['Texas', 'size'] = 'background-color: green'
    df1.loc['Florida', 'veterans'] = 'background-color: red'
    df1.loc['Maine', 'armored'] = 'background-color: red'
    #return color df
    return df1      

df.style.apply(create_colors, axis=None)
```

[image: table1]

Comment: Thanks jezrael. But what if I do not want to highlight a range of cells, I only want to highlight the 4 specific cells that I mentioned above?

Comment: Then use `df.style.applymap(green, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Arizona', 'company']).applymap(green, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Texas', 'size']).applymap(red, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Florida', 'veterans']).applymap(red, subset=pd.IndexSlice['Maine', 'armored'])`

Comment: Thanks  jezrael , this is exactly the answer that I am looking for!

Comment: A quick question jezrael, how to make the text of a specific cell bold? Any quick suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: add `font-weight: bold;` - use `'background-color: green'; font-weight: bold`, am not sure if `;` or `,` between

Comment: Super, nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example from http://melissagymrek.com/python/2014/01/12/ipython-tables.html

```
from ipywidgets import *
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3], "y":[6,4,3], "z":["testing","pretty","tables"], "f":[0.023432, 0.234321,0.5555]})
pt = PrettyTable(df)
pt


# Set cell style using a CellStyle object
pt = PrettyTable(df, tstyle=TableStyle(theme="theme1"), center=True)
cs = CellStyle()
cs.set("background-color", "red")
cs.set("color", "white")
pt.set_cell_style(style=cs)
pt
```

http://melissagymrek.com/python/2014/01/12/ipython-tables.html